# Ctrl+Alt+Del Screen Fade out on Windows 8

Tags: windows-8-preview

After pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Delete</kbd> in the Windows 8 RTM. The "control" screen comes up as in previous versions of windows allowing me to open Task Manager, Lock the computer ...etc but  it quickly fades to a completely black screen in less than 3 seconds.

The issue had a latency period and did't occur immediately after install. Has anyone come across this same issue or is there a fix for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured it out. It was a problem with my Samsung monitor and it's dyanmic contrast feature. After disabling it I no longer have the problem.